# Using Territory Management Users for Dynamic Sender Profiles

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, custom-reports, territory-management

I was wondering if anyone has ever come across the use of territory users being used as dynamic sender profiles for a one-to-one direct marketing experience.

The issues I am currently experiencing are the ability to synchronise system objects via the Marketing Cloud connector as they are not visible and the object permissions permit access to these objects due to limitations of the standard API being utilised via the connector retrieves objects based on object permissions.

I did however manage to generate [Custom Report Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=5) in Sales Cloud and import them using the **Interactions > Import (SF Report)** method because the **Object Import** method produces an error for some of the system objects as not all of them have retrievable permissions as mentioned so this is not the greatest solution, I am also worried here about scalability and timeout issues due to automation limitations of 30 minutes per activity.

The other solution I attempted successfully was performing direct AMPScript lookups to the Salesforce Objects within the DynamicSenderProfile content code block but I have to perform multiple lookups and even some looping to achieve this which I am concerned about performance issues at the time of send but it is working and could be an option.

```
%%[
/* Dynamic Sender Profile for X Territory Regions */
set @subscriberKey = 'ContactId' /* can be a lead or contact id */
set @type = 'Contact' /* can be a lead or a contact */

/* check if subscriber is a contact */
if @type == 'Contact' then

set @r1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'AccountId', 'Id', '=', @subscriberKey)

/* check if AccountId is found */
if RowCount(@r1) > 0 then

  set @row1 = Row(@r1, 1)
  set @accountId = Field(@row1,"AccountId")

  /* get the territories associated with the account matched */
  if not empty(@accountId) then

    set @r2 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('AccountUserTerritory2View', 'Territory2Id, UserId', 'AccountId', '=', @accountId)

    /* check if territories exist */
    if RowCount(@r2) > 0 then

      /* initialise loop breaker */
      set @loopBreaker = 0

      /* loop through each territory2 id */
      for @i = 1 to RowCount(@r2) do

        /* avoid any further processing if X territory has been found */
        if @loopBreaker != 1 then

          set @row2 = Row(@r2, @i)
          set @territory2Id = Field(@row2,"Territory2Id")
          set @userId = Field(@row2,"UserId")

          /* get territory name */
          set @r3 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Territory2', 'Name', 'Id', '=', @territory2Id)

          /* check if territory name exist */
          if RowCount(@r3) > 0 then

            set @row3 = Row(@r3, 1)
            set @territoryName = Field(@row3,"Name")

            /* check if this contacts account has X territory type assigned */
            if IndexOf(@territoryName, 'CPP') > 0 then

              set @r4 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('User', 'Name,Email', 'Id', '=', @userId)

              set @row4 = Row(@r4, 1)
              set @senderName = Field(@row4,"Name")
              set @senderEmail = Field(@row4,"Email")
              set @loopBreaker = 1 /* result found and break for loop */

              ]%%
              <!-- placed in div for testing purposes -->
              <div>
                Sender Name: %%=V(@senderName)=%% <br>
                Sender Email: %%=V(@senderEmail)=%%
              </div>
              %%[

            endif /* END check if this contacts account has X territory assigned */

          endif /* END check if territory name exist */

        endif /* END avoid any further processing if X territory has been found */

      next @i /* END loop through each territory2 id */

    endif /* END check if territories exist */

  endif /* END get the territories associated with the account matched */

endif /* END check if AccountId is found */

endif /* END check if subscriber is a contact */

]%%
```

There is a lack of documentation around this use case and I have been unsuccessful in finding any online material.

I was wondering if anyone else has had similar experiences and how you dealt with the systems limitations?

Comment: Hey Chris, Any chance of showing he AMPScript you were using in the Dynamic Sender Profile to help illustrate your specific use case? I can't easily visualise what you're trying to do and maybe the code that "works" might help illustrate.

Comment: Hey @Macca, not a problem, I have edited the above, this code works but it takes time because it talks directly to the CRM object multiple times and also has to loop until it finds the relevant territory type as there are many to many relationships with Territory Management unfortunately. I was hoping to reduce this load by importing the objects via the 'interactions import' method and then run a query to get a flat result that would mean I would only require potentially 1 lookup via `AMPScript` as it would process much faster. Let me know your thoughts?